# What tools can I use to find out why maven3 searches for really old internal SNAPSHOTs?

Tags: maven-3

I'm trying to upgrade my company from maven2 to maven3 and one blocker is a weird phenomenon whereby when I activate a certain profile the maven reactor starts searching for tons of old dependency information (for 10+ minutes until it runs out of memory).

I've seen that kind of behavior if there's a dependency that has a range (e.g. "[3.0,)") but I'm pretty sure I've wiped all those out.

Using mvn dependency:tree and mvn help:effective-pom won't show me if there are any range dependencies and grepping for *[, ], (* or *)* in pom.xml files turns up nothing, so I'm a little stumped at the moment about where to poke next.

For an example of what I'm talking about, in my pom I've got this profile activation section:

```
   <profile>
       <id>demo</id>
       <activation>
           <property>
               <name>client</name>
               <value>demo</value>
           </property>
       </activation>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
               <artifactId>client-demo</artifactId>
               <version>3.32.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </profile>
```

Then when I run this on the command line:

> mvn -Dclient=demo jetty:run

The output is thousands and thousands of searches for pom data for every historical SNAPSHOT that's ever existed of my client-demo artifact:

```
    ....snip.....
    Downloading:https://nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/mycompany/client-demo/2.16.7-SNAPSHOT/client-demo-2.16.7-SNAPSHOT.pom 
    [WARNING] The POM for com.mycompany:client-demo:jar:2.16.7-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available 
    Downloading: https://nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/mycompany/client-demo/2.16.8-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 
    Downloading: https://nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/mycompany/client-demo/2.16.8-SNAPSHOT/client-demo-2.16.8-SNAPSHOT.pom 
    [WARNING] The POM for com.mycompany:client-demo:jar:2.16.8-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available 
    Downloading: https://nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/mycompany/client-demo/2.16.9-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 
    Downloading: https://nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/mycompany/client-demo/2.16.9-SNAPSHOT/client-demo-2.16.9-SNAPSHOT.pom 
    [WARNING] The POM for com.mycompany:client-demo:jar:2.16.9-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available 
    Downloading: https://nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/mycompany/client-demo/2.16.10-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 
    Downloading: https://nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/mycompany/client-demo/2.16.10-SNAPSHOT/client-demo-2.16.10-SNAPSHOT.pom
    ....snip.....
```

EDIT:: Some more info.

This problem appears to be related purely to the inclusion of an additional dependency via profile activation, and not with the dependency itself.  For example, if I get rid of the profile and directly depend on the com.mycompany.client-demo-3.32.0-SNAPSHOT the bad behavior is not exhibited.  So it's something to do with the way the reactor handles profile-activated dependencies...I think

Comment: Could you show all the dependencies of your pom?

Comment: I could, but this artifact is "at the end" of a pretty long dependency hierarchy (i.e. depends on libraries that depend on libraries, that depend....you get the picture).  I could show you mvn dependency:tree, but that's post-profile application, and there's the problem.
I'll post the pom.xml tomorrow morning and see if that helps.

Comment: The problem is based on your dependencies which are added by using a dependency which is added via a profile which is really weird and really bad. Furthermore the output shows that you are trying to use other dependencies which are not in your repository (nexus). Apart from that its really bad practice to define version ranges. To test such a builds its best to wipe out the whole local repository and try to build (mvn clean package).

Comment: @khmarbaise - Why is conditional inclusion of dependencies a bad thing?  It's basically a poor man's OSGI.  Also, it's not true that I'm trying to use other dependencies that are not in my nexus repository: maven is scanning for them for some reason (that's why I posted this question) and not finding them because we get rid SNAPSHOTs older than 90 days.  Finally, I don't think I'm defining version ranges anywhere, but if I were, do you know what tool(s) I could use to track down where the version range is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

In your situation I would try a few things, like `help:effective-pom`, just to see if there was anything that surprised me. Also, `mvn -X -Dclient=demo clean install` and then watch the logs to see if you can figure out where the bad behaviour is coming from.

My only other thought is that maybe there is a circular dependency somewhere ... client-demo:X-SHAPSHOT depending on other-lib:Y-SNAPSHOT, depending on client-demo:(X-1)-SNAPSHOT ... but I suspect the output would be different in that case.

What happens when you build client-demo?